# mysql.jdbc.driver Class not found exception in private jvm after deployment local server it is working

Tags: java, jdbc

I have created a jsp servlet application through netbeans which connect to mysql database and local server and it is working properly. Mysql connector jar file is in the lib folder. But after deploying in to mochar server (private jvm) it is showing

> class not found expception `Class.forName("mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

How to resolve it?

Comment: post full stack of your exception

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure mysql connector jar is present in the tomcat lib folder.
(tomcat-home)/common/lib in case of tomcat5 and in (tomcat-home)/lib in case of tomcat7